# Firebase child listener on child moved

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to rearrange items in list through firebase child moved in firebase child listener. But the item to be moved replaces the item at the new position. The sorting is however than properly when I scroll up and down

```
      query.observe(.childMoved) { dataSnapshot in
        if let value = dataSnapshot.value as? [String: Any],
            let index = self.friends.index(where: {$0.fuid == dataSnapshot.key}) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
            
            let movedPost = friendsModel(snapshot: dataSnapshot)
            
            self.friends.remove(at: index)
            self.friends.insert(movedPost, at: 0)
            
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)], with: .none)
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            
        
    }
    
   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.childMoved` listener gets called with the `DataSnapshot` that was moved **and** the `previousSiblingKey`, which is the key of the item **after** which you need to reinsert the snapshot in your `friends` list. Since your code doesn't use `previousSiblingKey`, it doesn't have enough information to process the move correctly.

See the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#observe_:andprevioussiblingkeywith:withcancel: